# Convert T-SQL to Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following T-SQL:

```
Select 
    MESReportHeaderID
From Report.MESReportHeader
Where 
    MESReportHeaderID IN (Select ParentID From Report.MESReportHeader) And 
    IsLeafLevel = 0
```

This would be fairly trivial to convert to Linq, if it wasn't for the IN statement. Could anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: isn't that the same as selecting everything that has a parentID and isLeafLevel = 0??

Comment: @Gage - Yes, if this was the whole query. I've tried to simplify it a bit by leaving off unnecessary clutter. There is more to it than what is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways to do it, but I think this is a pretty straight-forward translation using extension methods.

```
var headerIDs = ctx.ReportHeaders
                   .Where( r => ctx.ReportHeaders
                                   .Select( rh => rh.ParentID )
                                   .Contains( r.MESReportHeaderID )
                                && !r.IsLeafLevel )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from r in reportHeaders
where reportHeaders.Any(r2 => r2.ParentId == r.MESReportHeaderID)
```